# Link only clickable on border?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of links encased in a border with a background... for some reason, the link is NOT clickable on the text, i.e., the cursor does not change to a hand on the link. It is only clickable on the BOTTOM border.... not sure why.

When I change around some of the CSS like the padding/margins/float, sometimes the links aren't even clickable at all. What could possibly be causing this??

**THE CODE**

```
<div id="teams">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="addyankees.php">Yankees</a></li>
    <li><a href="addphillies.php">Phillies</a></li></ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#teams {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    left: -25px;
}

#teams a{
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

#teams li {
    background: #EEE;
    padding: 7px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75px;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: 2px solid #C8C8C8;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**SOLVED**

There was an invisible element blocking it. Credit to kei.

Comment: I plugged your code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YVynj/) and it worked fine...

Comment: Looks fine to me. What browser are you using? Same code as above: http://jsfiddle.net/zm984/

Comment: @hughes @ngen Google chrome 12.0.742.100, could that be the problem?

Comment: @Tory in Chromium 12.0.742.91, it works too

Comment: Right-click on the link and `Inspect element`. See if there are any transparent elements overlapping the link.

Comment: I've had issues where the browser caches data weirdly when updating a page and css file a lot causing links to not work correctly, photo's to not size properly and borders and such to not behave how they are intended. The fact that people are running it through jsfiddle on many browsers just fine leads me to believe you might want to clear your history and cache and see if anything changes.

Comment: @kei You're a boss. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the link and `Inspect element`. See if there are any transparent elements overlapping the link.